# how to create the type or interface of any object in vscode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to create a type (or interface) by copying the type of a complex object that I import from a library.
By example, in the picture below it's the object Text coming from react-three/drei.
[image]

When I point the object i got a complex type as you can see. How can I copy paste this type definition into a

```
type Exemple={
..}
```

?
I am creating a react ref to this object and I don't know how to initiate this ref.

```
const reftext = useRef<?>(null!);
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, that image is so small, it's not legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator. `typeof` exists in JavaScript, but when it's used in a type annotation (or any place dealing with TypeScript types), TypeScript uses `typeof` to get the actual type.

```
type ComplexType = {
  fName: string | number;
}

const complexObj: ComplexType = {
  fName: 'Bill'
};

type TypeCopy = typeof complexObj; // type TypeCopy = { fName: string | number; }
const newObj: TypeCopy = {
  // fName: true, // ERROR
  fName: 5
};
```